# Android background updates

Tags: android

I have set my app to update four xml feeds in the background (if a user has selected the option) via an `AlarmManager` and a `BroadcastReceiver`.

This works perfectly on a wi-fi network, however, sometimes if it is using the mobile network for data and the process is a bit slower, by the 2nd or 3rd feed, the feed isn't fully fetched and I get an `ParseException` saying "unexpected end of document".

Is this a case of `BroadcastReceiver` not being the right option, or is it something else?

Comment: Some more information would be very helpful. How are you fetching the feeds? Who's throwing the ParseException?

Comment: The feeds are fetched with a input stream reading into a document builder, but it works fine on WiFi so I don't think that's the problem, it's most likely the 10 second limit. Do you have any tutorials for services on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you download the xml feeds? You have to ensure that the data is downloaded correctly.

Also, if you the BroadcastReceiver approach for doing batch background task is better to start a service (when you receive the broadcast event) and that the service do the "weight job" because if the broadcast receiver handler longs more than 10 secs the user will receive a Force Close message and the task will not be complete.

Comment: brilliant thank you so much, it must be the 10 second problem. Any tutorials you can link me to on using Services (never used one before)?

Comment: I don't know any tutorial about it, I had the same issue time ago and read it on the Advanced Android book of Mark L. Murphy